# What should be included on an About page/form?

Tags: ui, builds

I was looking to add a simple form that states my project's build number on a form to quick identify what version I am running. Then I realized I'm not sure what fits on an about page.

In my highschool projects I would make silly splash screens with this info, with images and other unnecessary information.

What are standard/appropriate elements to include on an "About" page in an application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only time I ever use About windows is to view the Version Number of the application, and possibly the application name to know what version of the application I'm running (eg. VS 2010 Express, Premium, Ultimate, etc)

So really I'd leave it at nothing more than a Logo/Name, and a Version Number. If you have a modular system, I'd have version numbers for each module loaded as well.